# Confusing documentation of flock(2)

Tags: c, linux

> If a process uses open(2) (or similar) to obtain more than one
>   descriptor for the same file, these descriptors are treated
>   independently by flock(). An attempt to lock the file using one of
>   these file descriptors may be denied by a lock that the calling
>   process has already placed via another descriptor.

If **flock()** treats the descriptors independently, why locking the file using one of the file descriptors would be denied by a lock placed via another descriptor? What does *independent* here mean?

Also if I unlock one of the descriptor, would other descriptors unlock as well?

Answer (score 1):

*treated independently by `flock()`* means that `flock()` will not "ask" one descriptor, when attempting to modify the other. However, it doesn't mean they are truly independent. If `flock()` tries to lock one, while the other is already locked, this attempt may block.

Think of it as 2-levels mechanism. `flock()` looks at only one descriptor at a time, but eventually, upon the lock attempt, the system tries to move to the dipper level and actually lock, and there the problem occurs.

> Also if I unlock one of the descriptor, would other descriptors unlock as well?

I'm not sure. This quote (below) states that this indeed is the case if a file has multiple descriptors from `fork(2), dup(2)`. However there is nothing that says so in the 2nd paragraph that treats multiple `open(2)` which leads me to believe that it is just not a good thing to do :)

From [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/flock.2.html):

> Locks created by flock() are associated with an open file description
>          (see open(2)).  This means that duplicate file descriptors (created
>          by, for example, fork(2) or dup(2)) refer to the same lock, and this
>          lock may be modified or released **using any** of these file descriptors.
>          Furthermore, the lock is released either by an explicit LOCK_UN
>          operation on any of these duplicate file descriptors, or when all
>          such file descriptors have been closed.
>
> If a process uses open(2) (or similar) to obtain more than one file
>          descriptor for the same file, these file descriptors are treated
>          independently by flock().  An attempt to lock the file using one of
>          these file descriptors may be denied by a lock that the calling
>          process has already placed via another file descriptor.